# Method returns result immidiately after first Async call is complete

Tags: java, multithreading, completable-future

Below mentioned is the code sample for reference.

```
public void myMethod() {
myService.getState().ifPresentOrElse(
id -> sendAsync(doSomeOpeartion1(), msg).
    .exceptionally(t-> {log.error("error 1")})
    .thenCompose(receipt -> sendAsync(doSomeOpeartion2(), msg )).
    .exceptionally(t-> {log.error("error 2")})
    .thenCompose(receipt -> sendAsync(doSomeOpeartion3(), msg )).
    .exceptionally(t-> {log.error("error 3")})
    .thenCompose(receipt -> sendAsync(doSomeOpeartion4(), msg )).
    .exceptionally(t-> {log.error("error 4")})
    .thenCompose(receipt -> sendAsync(doSomeOpeartion5(), msg ))).
    .exceptionally(t-> {log.error("error 5")})
    .thenAccept(receipt-> dosomeprocessing()), 
() -> {throw nwe TransactionException("");});
log.info("Processing complete");
}
```

My problem is that only doSomeOpeartion1() is executed and the the processing jumps to .thenAccept() and finally prints "Processing complete" message. Then it immediately returns the response to the calling method. However, in the background it continues to execute remianing methods that are doSomeOpeartion2(), doSomeOpeartion3(), doSomeOpeartion4() and doSomeOpeartion5().

How do I make my program to first execute all the async calls and only then finish the execution of myMethod()?

Comment: It seems you are just missing a `join()` at the end of the call chain…

Comment: Do you mean something  like .thenAccept(receipt-> dosomeprocessing().join()? Thanks anyways @DidierL for response.